# GraphQL error: variable junctionId of type Int! is used in position expecting bigint

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, graphql, apollo-client, hasura

When i tried to use apollo client to query the database, i shows me the error like this "GraphQL error: variable junctionId of type Int! is used in position expecting bigint"

Im trying to use hasura to connect the database which is a postgres timeseries database.

```
export const GET_TIME = gql`
query GetTime($junctionId: Int!, $type: String!){
  timeseries_vehicles_time_points(limit: 100, where: {vehicle_type: {_eq: $type}, id: {_eq: $junctionId}},order_by: {time: asc},distinct_on: time) {
    data_t:time
    data_y:value
  }
}
`;


const car = useQuery(GET_TIME, { variables: { junctionId: `${props.junctionId}`, type: "car" } })
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [the Hasura docs on supported types](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/api-reference/postgresql-types.html#implicitly-supported-types) to better understand the PostgreSQL types. The error you are being provided is stating the issue with your variable. You'll need to use `bigint` (or `bigint!` if it's a *non-nullable* field, such as in your example).

```
query GetTime($junctionId: bigint!, $type: String!){
  timeseries_vehicles_time_points(limit: 100, where: {vehicle_type: {_eq: $type}, id: {_eq: $junctionId}},order_by: {time: asc},distinct_on: time) {
    data_t:time
    data_y:value
  }
}
```